# How to rectify "PLS-00302: component must be declared" error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to compile below code but I am getting an error as:

> "PLS-00302: component 'DEPT_ID' must be declared".

```
DECLARE
DEPT_ID DEPARTMENTS.DID%TYPE;
DEPT_NAME DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
D_MID DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID%TYPE;
D_LID DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID%TYPE;
CURSOR C2 IS SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DID=1;
D_ROW C2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN C2;
LOOP
FETCH C2 INTO D_ROW;
EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(D_ROW.DEPT_ID||' | '||D_ROW.DEPT_NAME||' | '||D_ROW.D_MID||' | '||D_ROW.D_LID);
END LOOP;
CLOSE C2;
END;
```

Comment: Does your table really have both `DID` and `DEPT_ID` columns? The error suggests the latter does not actually exist... and what are the local variables for; they are unused at the moment?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for the comment. Departments table contain DID column, DEPT_ID is variable defined by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need to convert to :

```
DECLARE
-- DEPT_ID DEPARTMENTS.DID%TYPE;
-- DEPT_NAME DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
-- D_MID DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID%TYPE;
-- D_LID DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID%TYPE;
   CURSOR C2 IS SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DID=1;
   D_ROW C2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN C2;
 LOOP
   FETCH C2 INTO D_ROW;
  EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(D_ROW.DID||' | '||D_ROW.DEPARTMENT_NAME||' | '||
                       D_ROW.MANAGER_ID||' | '||D_ROW.LOCATION_ID);
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE C2;
END;
/
```

those local variables not needed, because their related columns' references are already exist in `C2%rowtype`, and those should be called by `D_ROW` with the column names. The error raises due to usage of local variables instead of those columns after `D_ROW.` prefix. E.g.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(D_ROW.DEPT_ID||' | '||D_ROW.DEPT_NAME||' | '|| 
                     D_ROW.D_MID||' | '||D_ROW.D_LID);
```

converted to

```
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(D_ROW.DID||' | '||D_ROW.DEPARTMENT_NAME||' | '||
                       D_ROW.MANAGER_ID||' | '||D_ROW.LOCATION_ID);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c71b44b6d15096b02ace96136cce0569)</kbd>

Comment: thank you @AlexPoole, you understood me :) OK, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @BarbarosOzhan for the comment. It is very helpful for beginners like me. My problem is resolved now. Thanks for clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
select owner, object_type, object_name
from all_objects
where object_name = 'DEPT_ID';
```

May be, there is an object with such a name have been declared before

[dba-oracle][1]http://dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00302.htm

Comment: Thanks @Ravshan for comment. There is no such object created.